# How to link static folder in Google app engine with a storage bucket

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-storage

Created a new python Flask app-engine python project and want to use the static files from Google cloud storage. I am using this `yaml.file`:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

Where in the app engine do you link to storage `https://storage.googleapis.com/<your-bucket-name>/static/` with `/static` in the app-engine? It is not clear from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use file stored on Google Cloud Storage as static folder in your App Engine environment. The solution proposed by the documentation is to have 2 sources (2 URL): one for the static file on GCS, the other for the backend on App Engine Flex.

The main issue with this design is the CORS issues. Personally I prefer another design.

- Set up a [HTTPS load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https)
- Create a [bucket backend to serve your source from GCS](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets)
- Create a [serverless NEG to serve your dynamic backend (on App Engine flex)](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless)
- Customize your [Path rule to route correctly the ressource to your respective backends](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map)
- Set a unique DNS in front of your HTTPS Load Balancer (no CORS management in this case)

Comment: Just curious, why would one do all that instead of just using regular GAE static files?  What is the benefit?

Comment: No real benefit, except the capacity to switch from GAE flex to Cloud Run for example. You can also view another benefit (which isn't one): you can update the static files as you want in GCS. With App Engine you need to redeploy a new version every time. It could be great for dev purpose, but for production (rollback, consistency between versions, canary or blue/green deployment,...) it's not a benefit!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am migrating to GAE for the first time. The penny dropped. I now realize I'm going about it the wrong way. On a single server having static/uploads, static/large_images, static/stylesheets all managed by the http server 'static' works. For GAE I have to separate the user uploaded content and that which goes with the source code.